# Getting the value of a <tr> from a dynamic table, but I only get the value of the first <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, jsonresponse

I'm trying to get the value of a row  when I click in it, but it only gets the value of the first tr even if I click in other tr. How can I get the value of the tr that I click?

I fill my table with a jsonresponse. here is my code.

Here is my code.

register.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%" border="0" id="miembrotb">
```

JsonResponse.js

```
$("#buscar_paciente").click(function(e) {
        var completo = $("#nombre").val();

        var input_string = completo;
        $.ajax({    
            url: "/datospacientejson",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                nombre: input_string,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
             success: function (json) {
                var jsonResponse = eval(json);
                    $("#miembrotb").empty();
                    $("#miembrotb").append('<tr><th>ID</th><th>NOMBRE</th><th>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</th></tr>');
                    $.each(jsonResponse, function (index, element) {
                        html = '<tr><td class="td1">'+jsonResponse[index]["fields"]["folio"]+'</td><td>'+jsonResponse[index]["fields"]["nombre"]+' '+jsonResponse[index]["fields"]["apellido_paterno"]+'<td>'+jsonResponse[index]["fields"]["fecha_nacimiento"]+'</td>'+'</tr>'
                        $("#miembrotb").append(html);
                    });
                },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(xhr.status + "ERROR EN BUSQUEDA DE INFORMACION DEL PACIENTE: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
});



//ON CLICK FUNCTION
  $("#miembrotb").click(function(){//click anywhere in a row
    alert($(this).find("tr").html());
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try following changes  '$('.td1').click'  then `$(this).html()`  this should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach click event to the specific `tr` element inside table with id `miembrotb`

```
$("#miembrotb tr").click(function(){//click anywhere in a row
       $(this).html();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is checking to see if an user clicks on the whole table, not on a specific row. That way, you don't know which row was clicked, and therefore can't get the information out of that row.

Also, when you do `$(this).find("tr")`, you're getting an array with all the elements that fill the query, so you're getting every single row that the table has.

What you need is, add a class to the rows, and then use the following code to add the eventlistener to them:

```
$('.table-class').click(function(){
    $(this).html();
});
```

This way, you'll get the html from the row that you clicked. Also, if you're dynamically creating them, you may need to attach the event listener after they're created.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the event listener, cause with the code that you share doesn't work, it grave all the information in the table.

Comment: Did you add a class to all the tables ? You can also do it like `$('#miembrotb tr).click'`